# System uptime without ssh login

Tags: linux, uptime

I have many linux servers which **I would like to check uptime** but I have to login to every one. Is this possible to check linux server running time **without ssh login** to it?

PS. My distributions are RHEL 7/8 and OL 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your servers are in a trusted, secure network, all in one or just a few network segments, installing an old `rwhod` service and its clients (`rwho` and `ruptime`) might also fit the bill. In Debian, those services are still packaged and installable by just installing two packages (`rwhod` and `rwho`), so if your distribution has it available and it fits your requirements, it might be the easiest solution.

RHEL 7 (and probably distributions related to it) has both the service and the clients packaged as a single `rwho` package; RHEL 8 and newer don't seem to include that package any more.

`rwhod` will send out a broadcast packet once per minute, listing the logged-in users and the current uptime, and listens for other similar broadcasts; the `rwho` and `ruptime` commands will take the reports collected by `rwhod` and output a report of all hosts that have been broadcasting within the last 11 minutes. `rwho` lists the users logged in each broadcasting host according to the last report received; `ruptime` lists the uptime of each reporting host.

Comment: My distributions are RHEL 7/8 and OL 8. This seems like a nice solution. Is it also available for these distributions?

Comment: You should **edit your question** to add that information in, since it is important for accurate answers, and these comments will eventually expire. And no, RHEL/OL 8 does not seem to include one, but RHEL 7 has both the server and the clients in a single `rwho` package.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a "xinetd" service, like that:

```
# cat /etc/xinetd.d/uptime
service uptime
{
    port        = 10200
        disable         = no
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        log_on_success += USERID 
        log_on_failure += USERID
        server          = /usr/bin/uptime
        user            = root
        instances       = UNLIMITED
        wait            = no
        log_type        = SYSLOG daemon debug
}

# service xinetd restart

# netstat -ant | grep 10200
tcp6       0      0 :::10200                :::*                    LISTEN  

# telnet localhost 10200
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
 08:59:39 up 23 days, 16:36,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have many servers, and I assume you will not just be interested in uptime, then the *correct* tool would be to load SNMP on each and have a monitoring station set up for their snmptrap responses. This is what the major players use. All the methods shown do not show missed boots, but SNMP will.

Answer (score 0):

I would not fulfill your precept "without ssh login", but maybe it is a possible botched solution.

My idea is to make a script to which you pass the list of IPs that you want to check, so that you automate the process of logging in to each machine and asking for the uptime.

Something like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo -e ""
else 
    read -a words -d "" < $1
    for ip in "${words[@]}"
    do
        if ping -c1 $ip &> /dev/null; then
            ssh $ip -t "echo \$(hostname): \$(uptime)" 2>/dev/null;
        else
            echo "No communication with $ip"
        fi
    done
fi
```

Where the file it receives as an argument would be:

```
192.168.1.1 192.168.2.1 192.168.3.1 192.168.4.1 192.168.5.1 192.168.6.1 192.168.7.1 192.168.8.1 192.168.9.1 192.168.10.1
```

The result would be like:

```
$ ./uptime-script.sh lan 
pc01-pc: 09:13:33 up 34 days, 1:40, 1 user, load average: 0.10, 0.16, 0.13
pc02-pc: 09:13:35 up 42 days, 2:50, 1 user, load average: 0.09, 0.10, 0.09
pc03-pc: 09:13:38 up 33 days, 23:37, 1 user, load average: 0.32, 0.19, 0.12
pc04-pc: 09:13:42 up 42 days, 2:15, 1 user, load average: 0.09, 0.13, 0.09
pc05-pc: 09:13:45 up 42 days, 2:08, 1 user, load average: 0.32, 0.25, 0.16
No communication with 192.168.6.1
pc07-pc: 09:13:58 up 42 days, 2:28, 1 user, load average: 0.20, 0.20, 0.18
pc08-pc: 09:14:01 up 6 days, 15:11, 1 user, load average: 0.77, 0.26, 0.14
server01-pc: 09:14:03 up 30 days, 3:02, 1 user, load average: 0.02, 0.05, 0.00
server02-pc: 09:14:05 up 30 days, 3:00, 1 user, load average: 0.01, 0.02, 0.00
```

It would be a simple way to monitor these computers.

Comment: I'm lost. How do you get the remote "uptime" on your script?

Comment: @Alberto I think I had a script error and the `ssh` command itself was missing, oops. It's already edited, as you can see, the connection is made by: `ssh $ip -t "echo \$(hostname): \$(uptime)" 2>/dev/null;`.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but (assuming that uptime is not the only thing of interest in your vast server fleet's health) I'd suggest using a proper tool for that job.

Consider using [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/), scraping all sorts of metrics from your fleet in 5-minute intervals, including metrics like uptime.

Well. To query a machine's uptime you'd go `node_time() - node_boot_time()` (that's uptime in seconds, feel free to do the maths for different time units), but that's essentially what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Also try rup. In debian packages rstatd on the server and rstat-client on the client.

Answer (score -3):

I have rewritten a new implementation of ruptime in a more modern way. It is here https://github.com/alexmyczko/ruptime

It encrypts the traffic, is not limited to a network. Easily adaptable/extensible. And will also work on macOS.

Special: rload shows cpu/mem/gpu usage in %.

Installation is classic. You download the release or master. Run make install as root.

If you have a Debian (or based on it) system, you can use the .deb files.

On macOS the preferred installation is via brew and my tap.

What does it look like?

```
$ ruptime # FQDN   State Uptime    Users    Load Averages 1' 5' 15'
dolphin.ocean.net   up   15+05:57  0 users  load 0.04 0.08 0.07
fish.ocean.net      up    4+21:27  0 users  load 0.22 0.25 0.25
tuna.ocean.net      up    4+21:27  0 users  load 0.20 0.30 0.42
```

Comment: This is not much different from [your previously deleted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/767407/70524). Please describe how to get this tool, how to use it, what the output looks like, etc. in the post.

Comment: Yes, while telling us about your tool is welcome, if you don't explain how this tool can be used to answer the question, then it isn't a valid answer and will get deleted. Please show how your tool can be used to show uptime without ssh.